# Understanding the MVC design pattern in Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Usually I just put together an app in any random way, as long as it works, but this means I don't pay any attention to any design patterns. My application currently makes extensive use of global variables (I carry an instance of my `AppDelegate` in every view controller to access properties I declared in my `AppDelegate.h`). Although it does what I want it to do, I've read this is not a good design practice.

So I want to start making my code "legit". However, I can't imagine my app right now without global variables. They are so important to the well-being of the app, but this must mean I'm doing something wrong, right? I just can't imagine how else I'd do some things. Take for example this:

[image]

You have two view controllers here, a `SideViewController` and a `MainViewController`. Using global variables, such as say if the entire application had one shared instance of `SideViewController` and `MainViewController` (`appDelegate.sideViewController` and `appDelegate.mainViewController`), I can easily communicate between the two view controllers, so that if I press "News Feed" in my `SideViewController`, I can tell my `MainViewController` to reload it's view.

I can't imagine, however, how this would be done if these were not global variables? If an event occurs in my `SideViewController`, how would I notify my `MainViewController`, in a way that is in accordance with design standards?

Comment: Are you using a Navigation Controller?

Comment: I'm using a navigation controller for the main contents of my app, however the current implementation of my SideViewController is not added to the navigation stack, but to the main application window via `[appDelegate.window addSubView:sideViewController.view]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't imagine, however, how this would be done if these were not
>   global variables? If an event occurs in my SideViewController, how
>   would I notify my MainViewController, in a way that is in accordance
>   with design standards?

The same way you do it now, except that the SideViewController gets its reference to the MainViewController from a different place.

How are these two view controllers created? It's likely that it happens in one of two ways:

1. One of the objects creates the other. In this case, maybe the MainViewController creates the SideViewController.
2. Some other object, such as the app delegate or another view controller, creates them both.

In the first case, the MainViewController has a reference to the SideViewController as soon as it creates it. It can store that reference in one of its own instance variables, so that it can always send messages to the SideViewController that it created. Similarly, the MainViewController can give the SideViewController a reference to itself (that is, to the MainViewController), and the SideViewController can store that and use it in the future to talk to its MainViewController.

The second case is similar -- if the app delegate (or some other object) creates both MainViewController and SideViewController, that object knows about both objects and can configure each with a reference to the other.

In both cases, the objects in question are able to communicate with each other just as easily as they ever did and there's no need for a global variable.

What I've explained above is perhaps the simplest way to accomplish what you asked for -- communication between two objects. There are a number of patterns that can be used to refine the relationship between those objects to make your code even better:

- **delegation:** Give SideViewController a delegate property, and define some protocol that establishes what SideViewController expects of its delegate. Implement that protocol in MainViewController. Make your MainViewController instance the SideViewController's delegate. SideViewController doesn't need to know exactly what type its delegate is -- it only cares that it's delegate implements the required protocol. This makes it easy to use SideViewController with something other than MainViewController if that opportunity arises, or to use it in a different project.
- **notifications:** SideViewController may not even need a delegate -- it can simply broadcast notifications about certain events to any object that happens to be listening. This is particularly effective if more than one object might need to know about something that happens in SideViewController, or if the objects that care about SideViewController's actions might change.
- **MVC:** Instead of telling MainViewController that something has changed, SideViewController just changes the data in the model. Whenever the MainViewController's view appears (or any other view controller's view, for that matter), the controller reads the data from the model and redisplays itself.

If you're interested, you might want to pick up a copy of Erik Buck's *Cocoa Design Patterns*, which explains these patterns and many others in great detail. Don't feel like you have to learn it all at once, or that it's all too much trouble. Learn a little bit at a time and see how it improves (or doesn't) your projects.

Comment: For case 1, if my `MainViewController` creates the SideViewController, then how can a `SecondaryViewController` access the `SideViewController`? With an `appDelegate.sideViewController`, this is easily done, but I'm reading that that kind of stuff shouldn't be in the AppDelegate.

Comment: Same questions: who creates `SecondaryViewController`? Also, *why* does `SecondaryViewController` need to access the SideViewController? Does it need to access *the same* SideViewController, or would it be better if it had it's very own SideViewController instance? Understanding the relationships between your objects is the first step toward organizing those relationships into something that's reliable and maintainable.